# A string contains certain characters only

Tags: vba

I am new to VBA and Syntax in VBA is not very friendly to me. I'm trying to validate a field which is string type. In that particular field, I want the string contains letters and comma and space only.

This is my current approach:

```
myArray = Array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", " ", ",", "-", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z")

If Not IsInArray(erName.Text, myArray) Then
   valid = False
   erName.ForeColor = vbRed
End If
```

And the IsInArray function is like the following:

```
Public Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
   Dim i
   For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
      If arr(i) = stringToBeFound Then
          IsInArray = True
          Exit Function
      End If
   Next i
   IsInArray = False
End Function
```

But this is not a very efficient approach because I don't want to loop over the array for every character in the string. Is there a simple way to perform this validation? Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RegEx solution

```
Function StringCheck(str)
    Set objRegEx = New RegExp
    With objRegEx
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Global = False
        .MultiLine = False
        .Pattern = "[a-zA-Z, ]*" 'alphabets + comma + space
    End With
    
    Set objMatch = objRegEx.Execute(str)
    If objMatch.Count = 1 Then
        If Len(str)=Len(objMatch(0).Value) Then 'if len of string matches the regex find
            StringCheck = True
        Else
            StringCheck = False
        End If
    Else
        StringCheck = False
    End If
End Function

MsgBox StringCheck("Pankaj Jaju") 'True
MsgBox StringCheck("Pankaj_Jaju") 'False
MsgBox StringCheck("Pankaj,Jaju") 'True
MsgBox StringCheck("Pankaj,Jaju 1234") 'False
```

Comment: FYI you can use the pattern "[^a-z, ]" and then just use the `Test()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to loop over every character to check whether it lies in your defined array. You just need to check whether the given character is in range of the permitted ASCII values :

ASCII value of character i >= 65 and <=90 (For upper case letters)

OR

ASCII value of character i >= 97 and <= 122 (For lower caase letters)

OR

ASCII value of character i == 44 (For comma)

OR

ASCII value of character i == 32 (For space)

You can define a check for these four conditions to avoid loop.

```
Public Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String) As Boolean


Dim i
   For i = 1 to Len(stringToBeFound)
  If (stringToBeFound(i) >= 65 and  stringToBeFound(i) <= 90) or (stringToBeFound(i) >= 97 and  stringToBeFound(i) <= 122) or
(stringToBeFound(i) = 44) or 
(stringToBeFound(i) = 32) Then
      IsInArray = True
      Exit Function
  End If


Next i


IsInArray = False
End Function
```

Comment: I may not be very sure about syntax.